# Why do so many npm package follow the convention of @scope/core

Tags: node.js, npm, package

Im researching the general conventions for npm packages and have noticed that many large package organisations such as babel, angular, material-ui and so on use @scope/core for their main package.

Why is this core and not main or something similar.